# python fileinput find and replace line

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to find a line starts with specific string and replace entire line with new string

I tried this code

```
filename = "settings.txt"
for line in fileinput.input(filename, inplace=True):
    print line.replace('BASE_URI =', 'BASE_URI = "http://example.net"')
```

This one not replacing entire line but just a matching string. what is best way to replace entire line starting with string ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to know what `old` is; just redefine the entire line:

```
import sys
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input([filename], inplace=True):
    if line.strip().startswith('BASE_URI ='):
        line = 'BASE_URI = "http://example.net"\n'
    sys.stdout.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the python 2 syntax. Since python 2 is discontinued, I will try to solve this in python 3 syntax

suppose you need to replace lines that start with "Hello" to "Not Found" then you can do is

```
lines = open("settings.txt").readlines()
newlines = []
for line in lines:
    if not line.startswith("Hello"):
        newlines.append(line)
    else:
        newlines.append("Not Found")
with open("settings.txt", "w+") as fh:
    for line in newlines:
        fh.write(line+"\n")
```

Answer (score -1):

This should do the trick:

```
def replace_line(source, destination, starts_with, replacement):

    # Open file path
    with open(source) as s_file:
        # Store all file lines in lines
        lines = s_file.readlines()
        # Iterate lines
        for i in range(len(lines)):
            # If a line starts with given string
            if lines[i].startswith(starts_with):
                # Replace whole line and use current line separator (last character (-1))
                lines[i] = replacement + lines[-1]

    # Open destination file and write modified lines list into it
    with open(destination, "w") as d_file:
        d_file.writelines(lines)
```

Call it using this parameters:

```
replace_line("settings.txt", "settings.txt", 'BASE_URI =', 'BASE_URI = "http://example.net"')
```

Cheers!

Comment: downvote for using `for i in range(len(lines))` and then `lines[i]` etc. Instead open both source / destination files, iterate on the source file and write the result to destination file. no need of any intermediate list.
What if the source file is huge and you load it to memory?

Comment: Oh you're right! My bad! Thanks for your input :)